# Nested Form and database update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm quite new to rails, so my question may seem noobish.

I have HABTM self association. A product can become a "COMBO" of products, having N products.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :combo_elements, class_name: "ComboElement", foreign_key: :combo_id
  has_many :element_combos, class_name: "ComboElement", foreign_key: :element_id
  has_many :combos, :through => :element_combos
  has_many :elements, :through => :combo_elements

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :elements
end

class ComboElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :combo, :class_name => 'Product'
  belongs_to :element, :class_name => 'Product'
end
```

With the above code, I can list all "elements" of a combo. Also I can list all "combos" a product is part of (the ComboElement table has a combo_id and an element_id)

Here is my form

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :elements, @element do |b| %>
  <%= b.input :element_id, :collection => Product.all.collect{ |t| [t.name, t.id ]}, selected: b.object.id %>
  <%= b.link_to_remove "Remove this element" %>
<% end %>
```

I can successfully list all Products a combo has, but whenever I try to update, it simply doesn't work.

My Product controller has the following code

```
def product_params
  params[:product].permit(:name, :price, elements_attributes: [:id, :element_id, :_destroy])
end
```

I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!